# What am I summing over in the Lagrangian of a BF theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, topological-field-theory

I'm reading the article [A pure Dirac's canonical analysis for four-dimensional BF theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4421). But when I get to the action, written as
$$S[\text{A},\textbf{B}]=\int_M \textbf{B}^{IJ}\wedge\textbf{F}_{IJ}(A),$$
I don't know what I'm summing over (what are the $\textbf{B}^{IJ}$ and $\textbf{F}_{IJ}$ supposed to be? What does "internal indices" mean?). Here $F^{IJ}=dA_{IJ}+A_I^{\phantom{K}K}\wedge A_{KJ}$ is the curvature of the Lorentz connection 1-form $A^{IJ}$ and $B^{IJ}$ is a set of six $SO(3,1)$ valued 2-forms.

From what I've managed to gather, the $B^{IJ}$ are like the "components" of $B$ when it is viewed as an element of a Lie algebra, but I don't even know if this has any sense.

I'd appreciate any reference that can guide me to a better understanding of these objects.

Comment: *What does "internal indices" mean?* It means non-Lorentz indices. Have you studied Yang-Mills theories like QCD?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't. Could you explain a little what are non-Lorentz indices?

Comment: I don’t know anything about BF theory. But in a gauge theory like QCD, fields carry “internal” indices related to the gauge symmetry of the theory… SU(3) for QCD. These indices distinguish, for example, “red” quarks from “blue” and “green” ones. The gauge symmetry is a kind of “unitary rotation in color space”, with “color space” being an “internal” space having nothing to do with spacetime.

Comment: Oh, thanks! That makes a little more sense, then I just have to identify the internal space in which I'm working.